# How to split a stream to multiple streams based on some ID then debounce them?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a publisher that emits an object which contains a few params. In the object, one of the params (called optionId) distinctly identifies an option. I'd like to debounce instances of that emission. However, if a new optionId shows up, I'd like to start a new clock, and start a new debounce.

Consider a stream like this:

Time in seconds: optionID emitted at source | what `debounce(3 seconds)` gets me | what I need //`-` means no event emitted.

```
00: 1 | - | -
01: 1 | - | -
02: - | - | -
03: - | - | -
04: - | 1 | 1
05: - | - | -
06: 3 | - | -
07: 1 | - | -
08: 3 | - | -
09: 1 | - | -
10: - | - | -
11: - | - | 3
12: - | 1 | 1
13: - | - | -
```

Comment: Disclosure: I borrowed the languages from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876356/group-and-debounce-observable

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing has nothing whatever in common with what the Rx `groupBy` does. Thus your title is misleading.

Perhaps you are also misusing the word "debounce"? Debouncing has to do with *timing*, and nothing in your diagram shows anything about that either. Debouncing has nothing to do with *what* values arrive; it simply insists upon a big gap of empty time before it will pass any value downstream at all (namely the most recent value).

It seems to me more likely that you simply want the `removeDuplicates()` operator. That would result in `1,3,1,3,1,3,1` which is exactly the output you give.

---

Okay, now that you've reworded the question, it occurs to me that you might be looking for something like this (this is just a demo, but it will give you the idea):

```
    let pub = [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,3,1].publisher
        .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(1)) { num in
            Just(num).delay(for:.seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        }
        .share()
    let p1 = pub
        .filter { $0 == 1 }
        .debounce(for: .seconds(1.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    let p2 = pub
        .filter { $0 == 3 }
        .debounce(for: .seconds(1.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    p1.merge(with: p2)
        .sink { print($0, Date().timeIntervalSince1970) }
        .store (in: &storage)
```

What I'm doing here is exactly what you said: I'm splitting the stream into two streams, based on whether this is a 1 or a 3, and I'm debouncing *each* of those streams before joining them back together.

The result is:

```
1 1614228919.57355
3 1614228922.823595
1 1614228923.923283
3 1614228925.0221992
1 1614228926.12345
```

If you think about those numbers, you'll see that we are indeed debouncing each value (1 or 3) separately.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the example is bad. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well so far my answer stands.

Comment: It seems with `removeDuplicates`, I will get 3 at second number 7 instead of second number 9, no?

Comment: I have updated the example to make it clearer what I meant by split-and-debounce.

Comment: I’ve added more to my answer.

Comment: It seems I had the classic XY problem. Thank you for helping out.
Considering your updated answer, I think it will work if I know a finite set of optionIDs that can be emitted. However, in my case, optionID is a base64 string so I cannot declare all the `pub.filter{...` line for each optionID. (I think the problem stands even if the optionID is Int). Is there a way to work around that?