# How to make observable debounceTime conditional

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple debounce on an element input event like so:

```
Observable
        .fromEvent(this.elInput.nativeElement, 'input')
        .debounceTime(2000)
        .subscribe(event => this.onInput(event));
```

I would like to make the debounce conditional based on the value of the event when emitted, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 59):

Yes, that's completely possible. Just make use of the `debounce` operator instead of `debounceTime`. It is passed a selector function that receives the previous operators notifaction when invoked.

In your example:

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounce, of, timer } from 'rxjs/operators';
//...
fromEvent(this.elInput.nativeElement, 'input')
    .pipe(debounce(ev => ev.hasSomeValue ? timer(2000) : of({})))
    .subscribe(event => this.onInput(event));
```

The selector function expects an `ObservableLike` and waits for it to emit before forwarding the last notification that `debounce` received. All other notifications are discarded, like with `debounceTime`. You can use `EMPTY` to immediately forward the notifcation without any timeout (though this will be async, see below)

From [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debounce):

> Though not as widely used as debounceTime, debounce is important when the debounce rate is variable!

**Note:** Debounce will always asynchronously schedule the forwarding of the last value, even if the inner Observable emits instantly. To avoid this, you'd have to create a second observable and use `filter` to avoid `debounce` altogether.

Comment: EMPTY didn't work for me. I didn't get result back from observable subscribe. I used this instead: debounce(value => value ? timer(300) : timer(0)).

timer(0) instead of EMPTY.

Comment: @Maichel Yep, EMPTY doesn't fire the observable. Nothing happens.

Comment: Good find, I've edited my answer

Comment: In mine case better to use `timer(0)` instead of  `of({})`. as In pair with `buffer` it skips the first value.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answer works if no variables are to be processed by the pipe. Plus passing 0 and asap to debounceTime (as so: `debounceTime(0, asap)`) does mean the next operator will be immediately called. In fact, once you use debounceTime you may experience a half second delay anyway, which is way too long in some cases.

So, after long time messing up with `iif` and friends, I decided to copy paste debounceTime and modify it to take a conditional function. Any ideas / improvements are most welcome:

This is intended for Angular 9 and may raise warnings/errors with previous versions.

Use it just like you would with debounceTime, just pass a conditional function as first boolean parameter. If it is true, it will debounce, if false it will immediately continue.

Example:

```
observable$.pipe(
    conditionalDebounceTime(() => conditionFlag, 1000),
    tap(observedValue ... => ...)
    ...
```

conditional-debounce-time.ts

```
import {MonoTypeOperatorFunction, Observable, Operator, SchedulerLike, Subscriber, Subscription, TeardownLogic} from 'rxjs';
import {async} from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';

class ConditionalDebounceTimeSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
  private debouncedSubscription: Subscription|null = null;
  private lastValue: T|null = null;
  private hasValue = false;

  constructor(destination: Subscriber<T>,
              private conditionFunc: () => boolean,
              private dueTime: number,
              private scheduler: SchedulerLike) {
    super(destination);
  }

  protected _next(value: T) {
    this.clearDebounce();
    this.lastValue = value;
    this.hasValue = true;
    if (this.conditionFunc()) {
      this.add(this.debouncedSubscription = this.scheduler.schedule(dispatchNext, this.dueTime, this));
    } else {
      (<Subscriber<T>>this.destination).next(this.lastValue);
    }
  }

  protected _complete() {
    this.debouncedNext();
    (<Subscriber<T>>this.destination)!.complete();
  }

  debouncedNext(): void {
    this.clearDebounce();

    if (this.hasValue) {
      const { lastValue } = this;
      // This must be done *before* passing the value
      // along to the destination because it's possible for
      // the value to synchronously re-enter this operator
      // recursively when scheduled with things like
      // VirtualScheduler/TestScheduler.
      this.lastValue = null;
      this.hasValue = false;
      (<Subscriber<T>>this.destination)!.next(lastValue!);
    }
  }

  private clearDebounce(): void {
    const debouncedSubscription = this.debouncedSubscription;

    if (debouncedSubscription !== null) {
      this.remove(debouncedSubscription);
      debouncedSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.debouncedSubscription = null;
    }
  }
}

class ConditionalDebounceTime<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
  constructor(private conditionFunc: () => boolean, private dueTime: number, private scheduler: SchedulerLike) {
  }

  call(subscriber: Subscriber<T>, source: any): TeardownLogic {
    return source.subscribe(new ConditionalDebounceTimeSubscriber(subscriber, this.conditionFunc, this.dueTime, this.scheduler));
  }
}

export function conditionalDebounceTime<T>(conditionFunc: () => boolean, dueTime: number, scheduler: SchedulerLike = async): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.lift(new ConditionalDebounceTime(conditionFunc, dueTime, scheduler));
}

function dispatchNext(subscriber: ConditionalDebounceTimeSubscriber<any>) {
  subscriber.debouncedNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those answers won't work that great cause of the nature of javascript and the event loop. If you make something timer(0) its not instant, its still delayed and sent to the taskQue. In order to get the behavior right you would have to subscribe to the time which you pass to the debounceTime / delay / sampleTime and then you would need to make it so that they recreate the pipeline.

I don't see how thats done in the second solution either, however I didn't try it my self I just think this comment might help someone cause its hardly the fault of debounceTime but rather that for that 1 second something in your code executes and the stack is blocked to execute taskQue scripts.

Also its not possible to make the behavior much better cause you can't have a interval which is running in the stack continously, this would mean its a infinite while loop and it would block the stack and result in a frozen UI.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: I can't add an comment to the answers above cause of low reputation. The answers don't take into account the points covered by my comment. Sorry for the trouble.